# How to zoom in on google maps location?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

When I open the app, it shows the entire world and I have to keep zooming in to view the place properly.How do I make the camera zoom in about 11 times as if I were to keep double clicking?

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng( 10.625176, -61.354915))
                .title("Tru-Valu, Trincity Mall"));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[`GoogleMap`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html) has "move" and "animate" methods for positioning and zooming.

- [`moveCamera(CameraUpdate update)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#moveCamera(com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate)) which repositions the camera according to the instructions defined in the update.
- [`animateCamera(CameraUpdate update)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#animateCamera(com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate)) which animates the movement of the camera from the current position to the position defined in the update.

You can get [`CameraUpdate`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdate) object using [`CameraUpdateFactory`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory). Here are some examples.

- `CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(LatLng latLng)`

> Returns a CameraUpdate that moves the center of the screen to a
>   latitude and longitude specified by a LatLng object. This centers the
>   camera on the LatLng object.

- `CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LatLng latLng, float zoom)`

> Returns a CameraUpdate that moves the center of the screen to a
>   latitude and longitude specified by a LatLng object, and moves to the
>   given zoom level.

- `CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(float amount)`

> Returns a CameraUpdate that shifts the zoom level of the current
>   camera viewpoint.

You can find other helper methods in CameraUpdateFactory [documenation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory). Also, here is very usefull [documentation from Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/views#moving_the_camera) regarding moving the GoogleMap's camera.

So, if you would like to zoom at `Tru-Valu, Trincity Mall` place, this is how your code should look like

```
googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
        new LatLng(10.625176, -61.354915), 16f));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(lat, lng);
CameraUpdate yourLocation = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinate, 5);
map.animateCamera(yourLocation);
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Milad Nouri's answer, initially the user might not have Location on, and the [FusedLocationProvider](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi) won't have the last location yet, because the API client hasn't started. So, my trick for this is to save the user' last Latitude and Longitude to savedPreferences and load this location as the LatLng for the initial camera animation when the app starts.

I save the LatLng when it is updated last so it just remembers the last Latitude and Longitude that was updated for the user's location on the map.